# How to ensure last token in sequence is end-of-sequence token?

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am using the `gpt2` model from huggingface's `transformers` library. When tokenizing, I would like all sequences to end in the end-of-sequence (EOS) token.  How can I do this?

An easy solution is to manually append the EOS token to each sequence in a batch prior to tokenization:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')

text = ['Hello world.', 'I am program.']

text = [el + tokenizer.eos_token for el in text]

tokenized_text = tokenizer(text)
```

It seems like my solution is an inelegant solution for this task that is so commonplace that I expect there is some built-in way of doing this.  I haven't found anything about this in the documentation—is there a way?

Edit: I want to do this in order to train a GPT-2 to generate specific kinds of responses to input sequences.  Without the end-of-sequence token during training, performance was poor, and the model generated much too much text.

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you want to do that (i.e. your use case)? The library does indeed not offer a built-in method for that.

Comment: @cronoik I edited my question to answer that.  Please let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: @cronoik the drop in performance in leaving out the EOS token was ~40% in F1 score.

Comment: I tried a few variants but they are all slower than your variant. Therefore, I would stick with it.